# PHP Booking System automatic update of MySQL database, without any user interaction.

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have created a booking system for a car rental company, and I have an issue with setting the availability of cars.

A brief example of how it works is that a single car, when it is booked out recieves a value of `yes` in a field within the database called `bookedout`

Ok, so say for examples sake that there is 10 cars (this is unrealistically small but demonstrates the point)

1 of these is a Audi R8.

Today's date is the 6th of march 2012.

A user books the car from the 26th of march to the 31st of march. But they place that booking through the website today. I cannot set the `bookedout` value to `yes` straight away or the website will actually consider that car unavailable from the 6th of march to the 31st of march.

This scenario would loose a company money.

So I am looking for something like a script that sits on the server, checks the current date and then checks the database every day. And for example if there is a booking due to start on today's date, it would change the value within the database so the car is unavailable to book from this day.

In turn I could also adapt it to change the value back on the date on which the car is due to be returned.

I am not specifically looking for code (although I wouldn't say no to examples), just a starting point for figuring things like this out as I have never done this before.

**Basically, I need a way to trigger a query, without any user interaction, on a certain date.**

Any help would be seriously appreciated. :)

Comment: There are 763 reasons why you should never store whether or not the car is booked along with the car - you have just found one. Because it's not a global car property. Cars are booked by reservations. Have another table, called `reservations` with `car_id`, `start_date` and `end_date` fields. Ta-da, no magical cron-queries needed.

Comment: You are trying to fix a symptom of the problem but not the cause of the problem. Your availablity system should be able to handle reservations for future dates. And your code should be able to query availablity for a requested date.

Comment: cron is a time based job scheduler. Follow @ColinMorelli's advice however.

Comment: @ColinMorelli Ok, I am happy to admit i haven't approached this in the correct way, so say I follow your advice, and create a reservations table. I am taking it that this would mean that before I allow a user to place a booking that I would just query the reservations table to see if there were any reservations between those dates for that car, if not allow them to book it, if there is it would return as car unavailable?

Comment: @Bohdi Look at my answer below for additional detail

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll flesh this out a little more in answer-form for you, though I'm not going to post any code because I don't think it's necessary to answer this particular question.

Your database structure should look something like this (a lot of fields that a car rental company would want - such as mileage, damage, etc - are left out for brevity):

**cars**

- car_id
- make
- model
- year

**customers**

- customer_id
- first_name
- last_name
- email_address

**reservations**

- reservation_id
- car_id
- customer_id
- start_date
- end_date

The idea is that you never store a booking status with the `car`. Rather, you create a `reservation` with `start_date` and `end_date` set to the dates of the reservation.

Your query to check cars that are available for a given date range would be:

```
SELECT
    c.car_id
FROM
    cars c 
    LEFT JOIN reservations r ON (
       c.car_id = r.car_id
       AND r.start_date <= $reservationEndDate
       AND r.end_date >= $reservationStartDate
    )
WHERE
    r.reservation_id IS NULL
```

And with this model, you never need to worry about running time-based jobs to update a cars reserved status. Although, to optimize your application, you may run a daily job that updates the cars status so you can quickly find out how many cars are available *today*.

**Additional Note**

As N.B. pointed out in the comments - you'll want to make sure your application doesn't allow conflicting date ranges in the reservations table. There's no unique index that can solve for this, so you'll need to handle this in your application logic - beware of race conditions. A possible solution would be to create a *temporary* reservation as soon as someone looks at a car for a certain date range.

**Another Additional Note**

N.B. Also had a good suggestion to avoid the above problem: use database triggers to validate it server-side. The database can reject the INSERT in the trigger if another booking was created that conflicts. This solution may very well be the best, as it keeps the validation as close to the data as possible (so you can't "forget" it in your application).

Comment: thats awesome, I just replied to your comment but that makes it a lot clearer. thank you :)

Comment: On top of a great answer (+1), I'd just point out that you need to make sure you don't write two (or more) entries into your reservations table with dates that collide. So on top of changing your approach, you'll have to think about how to avoid two users reserving the same car during the same time.

Comment: @N.B. Thanks for that - I edited the answer to include your comment

Comment: @ColinMorelli - just to add again (sorry) - you can handle validation via triggers (before insert) to check whether you'd get colliding dates. If yes, force database to raise the exception. That way there's no way anyone can write anything to the database and there are no classic error such as due to lag between db <> app, some records slipped trough etc.

Comment: @N.B. Included in the answer as well. Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you both, I understand. And I thank you both for the education

Comment: I am unsure if you are still here, but I've been playing around with your solution and it is a lot more flexible. However I store my cars individually, so there may be 10 dodge vipers, each would have its own row but a unique carID and registration. That's an ok way to go about it?

Comment: @Bohdi Absolutely - and that should be how it's done. If you have 10 of the same make/model cars (but they're each individual vehicles) they should be stored as separate cars. That way you can reference damage, insurance claims, reservations, mileage, etc to an individual vehicle

Answer (score 1):

The literal answer to your question is [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) (assuming you're running on a *nix system).

However, you really don't want to do that - it's very fragile, because you still have to query a table with bookings whenever you run the cron job; that means that now there are 3 places which know how car bookings work (the cron job, the bookings table, and your application).

It's far simpler to say that a car is unavailable to book by joining it to the bookings table; if there's a valid booking for a given date, the car can be considered unavailable.

Making some assumptions about your schema, it might be something like

```
select 'booked'
from   cars c, 
       bookings b
where  c.car_id = b.car_id
and    b.start_date < ?required_date 
and    b.end_date   > ?required_date
union
select 'free'
from   cars c, 
       bookings b
where  c.car_id = b.car_id
and    b.start_date >= ?required_date 
or    b.end_date   <= ?required_date
```

Comment: Thank you, +1 for an answe I understand and that makes more sense than my original method :)